# Base64 image data not working with loadfromJSON in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, base64, fabricjs

I am trying to load a json object which has a image object. Image object is having base 64 image data as background. But i am unable laod the loadFromJSON method.

Code:

```
var jsonDataSet = '{"objects":[{"type":"image","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":0,"top":0,"width":700,"height":600,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"selectable":false,"hasControls":true,"hasBorders":true,"hasRotatingPoint":true,"transparentCorners":true,"perPixelTargetFind":false,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"src":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAn4AAAFPCAYAAADTHsP1AAAgAElEQ…Lv/vuU1wVsyvXK+Kks1f6gffSCThZ1km3u6NFklCnFes//AbZzi+iGF3/7AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC","filters":[]}],"background":""}';

canvas.loadFromJSON (jsonDataSet);

canvas.renderAll();
```

It is displaying an error as `"Error loading data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAn4AAAFPCAYAAADTHsP1AAAgAElEQ…Lv/vuU1wVsyvXK+Kks1f6gffSCThZ1km3u6NFklCnFes//AbZzi+iGF3/7AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC "`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the latest fabric.js version it's a bug. I've fixed that with the pull request #800: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/pull/800.

BTW your base64 dataURL of your above code is not correct - it has three dots (lEQ…Lv/vuU).
Probably a side effect from copying.

Comment: Thank you very much. Added your changes and it is working as expected.

Comment: The three dots are not a side effect of copying they are actually added by fabric.js.  Look at the output in the console here: http://jsfiddle.net/h9q6Lorg/

Comment: They are not added by fabric.js. It's a bug/restriction of the console.log in the chrome devtools (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=464560).
http://jsfiddle.net/devxyrro/

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was not aware of this chrome devtools restriction. Thanks for the explanation.