# Images filled in the shapes are not loading with loadFromJSON in FabricJS

Tags: image, canvas, html5-canvas, loading, fabricjs

I have **JSON** data with fabric Rect object. When I try to load this **JSON** data on to fabric canvas with **LoadFromJSON**, Shapes are loading perfectly but patterns filled in the shapes are not rendering. The patterns are rendered only after clicking on shape.

I have copied my code in fabric Kitchen sink execute module and i tried to execute it. But it is also not working as expected.

**My Code:**

```
var jsonD = '{"objects":[{"type":"rect","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":222.92,"top":237,"width":100,"height":100,"fill":{"source":"http://www.convertingquarterly.com/Portals/1/images/industry-news/Brushfoil%20cross-hatch,%20Tru-Stainless%20paaterns.jpg","repeat":"repeat","offsetX":0,"offsetY":0},"overlayFill":null,"stroke":"black","strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"selectable":true,"hasControls":true,"hasBorders":true,"hasRotatingPoint":true,"transparentCorners":true,"perPixelTargetFind":false,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"rx":0,"ry":0,"x":0,"y":0}],"background":""}';
canvas.loadFromJSON(jsonD);
canvas.renderAll();
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have just updated from 1.1.6 to 1.2.9 and my image assets are also not showing when using loadFromJson!

What the heck changed?!

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350325/base64-image-data-not-working-with-loadfromjson-in-fabricjs/2323945
This was a bug - changes actually not included in all.js.
The problem with patterns exists also for image filters. Will look into it.

Comment: @Kienz any updates on this ? Pattern filled in the object is loading only after click on the canvas .